# Deploying Android App

Tags: android, database, deployment

I have developed a database application for Android. Now I want to make it available to deploy it. But I don't how to deploy it with the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you might have used sqlite database. Keep your sqlite database in your assets folder and create your apk. Android will take care of the rest.

```
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

where DB_Path = "/data/data//databases/"; and DB_Name = your database name

Comment: But when I refer to the database through openorcreate() method, it is created in /data/data/<app.package>location. Please tell me how can I use it from assets folder?

Comment: String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
  SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE); where DB_Path = "/data/data/<app.package>/databases/"; and DB_Name = your database name